# How to fix bug with unbeforeunload in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I have the follow code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {


              $.post(
                   'script/ratings.php', 
                    {
                    data: dataToServer,
                    slider: slider_position_value,
                    article: ARTICLE_NAME
                    },
                      function(data) {

                   });

 };
```

that works perfectly in IE and Mozilla. Of oourse, I know about the bug in Chrome due to this event doesn't appear. I need recipe to catch this event and make POST-request into it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeunload` event *does* work in Chrome. However, upon page leave, all requests, including AJAX, are cancelled.

To get your current code to work, use a synchronous request, by adding `async:false` to the `jQuery.ajax` set-up. **This blocks the UI till a response is received**, and is not recommended.

Comment: yes, I wasn't accurate in question. Thanks. I need to make AJAX-requestin beforeunload.

Comment: @Eugene That intention was clear to me. I've added a solution to my answer. I discourage the use of it, because it blocks the tab. A better method is to save the ratings periodically, or upon click of a button.

Comment: Yeeeh, thanks, it works. I get from server only the couple of byte, therefore delay is normal.

Comment: @Eugene Think about users who have a bad internet connection.

Comment: Ooo, in opera I found the same problem. Is any way to catch beforeunload in Opera?

Comment: @Eugene Opera does not support `beforeunload` until version 12.